# Cannot compile PL/SQL Procedure. Any suggestions?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

You guys have any idea on what could be the issue here?

```
    Create or Replace FUNCTION Something ( v_sno IN Supplier.SNO%TYPE) RETURN NUMBER IS
    l_cnt NUMBER;   
    BEGIN
       Select city, count (*) into l_cnt
       From Supplier
       Group by city;
     return l_cnt;
  END;
```

/

Comment: You cannot compile a plsql function in mysql if that's what you mean. and you seem to be attempting to push city and count into 1_cnt.

Comment: ah ur right. do u know how I would fix the code? @P.Salmon

Comment: Throw us the error you get, least will be able to know what database you are working on.

Comment: Tag youq question properly!!!  You tag MySQL and plsql.  So which one is you are using???  They're 2 completely different products.

Comment: Can you describe what you need the function to do?

Comment: You select two column, but only provide one variable to store the result in

Answer (score 0):

The function doesnt make sense as the input parameter is never being used. Solution for oracle/Mysql are below, might not be apt as i don't have 
your datamodel but will definitely guide you in the right direction.

If you are using aggregation with group by, that means multiple rows are being returned 
in which case your output will be a record set and that requires more change to the Function 
and the solution greatly depend on the type of database.

If you are on Oracle database then try below,

```
Create or Replace FUNCTION Something ( v_sno IN Supplier.SNO%TYPE) RETURN NUMBER IS
  l_cnt NUMBER;   
  BEGIN
     Select count (*) into l_cnt
     From Supplier 
     WHERE SNO = v_sno;
   return l_cnt;
END;
```

If you are on MYSQL you can write function as below,

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION Something(
    v_sno INT
) 
RETURNS INT
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE l_cnt INT;

    Select count (*) into l_cnt
    From Supplier 
    WHERE SNO = v_sno;

    RETURN (l_cnt);
END$$
DELIMITER;
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as i see,

1. you can handle expception.i suppose there is a too_many_rows error there.
2. you didn't use your param "v_sno" in query.
3. i am not sure that you know what you want. logically if you sent supplier no in function,it must always return 1.

anyway if you want to only compile.here it is.

```sql
CREATE OR replace FUNCTION Something (v_sno IN supplier.sno%TYPE) 
RETURN NUMBER 
IS 
  l_cnt NUMBER; 
BEGIN 
    SELECT Count (*) 
    INTO   l_cnt 
    FROM   supplier 
    WHERE  sno = v_sno; 

    RETURN l_cnt; 
EXCEPTION 
  WHEN OTHERS THEN 
             RETURN -1; -- there is some error. 
END;
```

Comment: Answer seems same as mine? Couldn't figure out the difference.

Comment: there is only exception's block as different.Buy you are right.I can remove code .